# How to use Flink streaming to process Data stream of Complex Protocols

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I'm using Flink Stream for the handling of data traffic log in 3G network *(GPRS Tunnelling Protocol)*. And I'm having trouble in the synthesis of information in a user session of the user.

**For example:** how to map the start and end one session. I don't know that there Flink streaming suited to handle complex protocols like that?

*p/s:*
We capture data exchanging between SGSN and GGSN in 3G network (use GTP protocol with GTP-C/U messages). A session is started when the SGSN sends the *CreateReq (TEID, Seq, IMSI, TEID_dl,TEID_data_dl)* message and GGSN responses *CreateRsp(TEID_dl, Seq, TEID_ul, TEID_data_ul)* message. 
After the session is established, others GTP-C messages (ex: UpdateReq, DeleteReq) sent from SGSN to GGSN  uses TEID_ul and response message uses TEID_dl, GTP- U message uses TEID_data_ul (SGSN -> GGSN) and TEID_data_dl (GGSN -> SGSN). GTP-U messages contain information such as AppID (facebook, twitter, web), url,...
Finally, I want to handle continuous log data stream and map the GTP-C messages and GTP-U of the same one user (IMSI) to make a report.

I've tried this:

```
val sessions = createReqs.connect(createRsps).flatMap(new CoFlatMapFunction[CreateReq, CreateRsp, Session] {
  // holds CreateReqs indexed by (tedid_dl,seq)
  private val createReqs = mutable.HashMap.empty[(String, String), CreateReq]
  // holds CreateRsps indexed by (tedid,seq)
  private val createRsps = mutable.HashMap.empty[(String, String), CreateRsp]


  override def flatMap1(req: CreateReq, out: Collector[Session]): Unit = {
    val key = (req.teid_dl, req.header.seqNum)
    val oRsp = createRsps.get(key)
    if (!oRsp.isEmpty) {
      val rsp = oRsp.get
      println("OK")
      out.collect(new Session(rsp.header.time, req.imsi, req.teid_dl, req.teid_ddl, rsp.teid_upl, rsp.teid_dupl, req.rat, req.apn))
      createRsps.remove(key)
    } else {
      createReqs.put(key, req)
    }
  }

  override def flatMap2(rsp: CreateRsp, out: Collector[Session]): Unit = {
    val key = (rsp.header.teid, rsp.header.seqNum)
    val oReq = createReqs.get(key)

    if (!oReq.isEmpty) {
      val req = oReq.get
      out.collect(new Session(rsp.header.time, req.imsi, req.teid_dl, req.teid_ddl, rsp.teid_upl, rsp.teid_dupl, req.rat, req.apn))
      createReqs.remove(key)
    } else {
      createRsps.put(key, rsp)
    }
  }
}).print()
```

This code always returns empty result. The fact that the input stream contains CreateRsp and CreateReq message of the same session. They appear very close together (within 1 second). When I debug, the *oReq.isEmpty == true* every time.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to map the start and end (of) one session"? Please give more details what you try to do.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I've just added more details about one session of user.

Comment: Which version of Flink are your using? Lately, the data stream API got a major refactoring (available in current master and will be part of Flink 0.10.0). Check out the new documentation of window processing in Flink https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html#windows To me, it seems as you want to partition your stream on user-id and use custom windows (where each window corresponds to a session). Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm using Flink 0.10-SNAPSHOT. The imsi (user-id) is only appear in CreateReq message. So I can not partition the stream on it.

Comment: I would recommend to use a small test data set, and debug in `LocalStreamEnvironment` or do LOG/printf debugging to get more insight.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I tried this *val sessions = createReqs.keyBy(teid_dl).connect(createRsps.keyBy(teid))* and it works. As you see, *CreateReq* is mapped to *CreateRsp* by *teid_dl == teid*. As this code, I think that Flink will connect a matrix of streams keyed? Where I can learn details about how Flink connect two streams?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I don't know how long *createReqs* variable in *FlatMap()* function will exist? In some case, CreateRsp may be losed, so I can not release *CreateReq* message in *createReqs*.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. If you group by key both streams and connect the keyed streams, the sub-streams of each key will be connected, ie, there will be one instance of your CoFlatMapFunction for each distinct key processing both corresponding sub-streams of the two input streams. The variables your CoFlatMapFunction will be there for the whole job (as long as there is not error). If you want to back up internal state, you need to use Flink's `OperatorState` class. See the documentation for more details: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html

Comment: Thank Matthias. I've done some test to understand more about *connect* streams. As you see, the **teid** is used to identify a user's session. For each **teid** will exist an instance corresponding of my CoFlatMapFunction. A **new teid** will generate to identify a new user's session and a **new instance** corresponding of my CoFlatMapFunction. The old instance can not be reused and also not be released. Thus, the memory will always continue to be increased. I don't know whether Flink have any mechanisms for this problem? Please, help me some idea.

Comment: I see. It is currently not supported by Flink to "expire" keys (as fas as I know) on non-window functions. As a workaround, you could introduce surrogate keys as an additional attribute and group on them. Using this "trick" a single instance of you *CoFlatMapFunction* will process multiple keys and you can drop old state manually in your user code. A second approach would be to build session-windows on the streams. This allows to release of sessions and thus clear the state.

Comment: I've found *session-windows* at [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Streams+and+Operations+on+Streams). But, I find out no the corresponding api in [Flink DataStream API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html). Does Flink not support session-window in 0.10 version?

Comment: Look into the docu section "Advanced Window Constructs" and Try something like this: `myStream.keyBy(0).window(GlobalWindows.create()).trigger(new MyTrigger()).evictor(new MyEvictor())`.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it is a bit difficult to see through the telco specifics here, but if I understand correctly you have at least 3 streams, the first two being the *CreateReq* and the *CreateRsp* streams.

To detect the establishment of a session I would use the *ConnectedDataStream* abstraction to share state between the two aforementioned streams. Check out this [example](http://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/exercises/accidentDelays.html) for usage or the related [Flink docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/apis/streaming_guide.html#co-operators).

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I've tried to use ConnectedDataStream as above. But something is woring!